# Simple Java web service router

Tags: routes, service

How do I setup programmatic web service forwarding from my webapp to an external web service?  I need something like tcpmon but then integrated into my webapp war so that my flash files can make web service calls back to the webapp that served them.  These calls are, in turn, would be routed to the external web service.  ESBs are too heavy weight for this type of vanilla routing.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jason Edwards's [Proxy Servlet](http://edwardstx.net/wiki/attach/HttpProxyServlet/ProxyServlet.java)